# How to create a logic app that can check for the number of rows with null value in Azure storage table?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a Azure storage table where i have 4 columns of data, i need to create a logic app that check for one specific column so if that column have less than 10 rows with null or empty value, i get notified by log app action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my logic app:

You can use `Get entities` to get the data in the table, and then initialize a variable to count：

[image]

Then you can loop through the obtained entities to confirm whether the specified column is null, if it is null, you can add 1 to the count variable.

Expressions used in `conditon`:

```
item()?['<your-column-name>']
```

[image]

Finally, you can use the condition to determine whether the count is less than 10, and send a notification if it is less than 10.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Frank Gong that answer my question, appreciate your guidance